# Generate a string of N random English words with NLTK/Python

Tags: python, string, random, nltk, vocabulary

Is there a way to generate a string of N random English words using NLTK/Python?

I am aware of NLTK's ability to generate sentences based on input text and a grammar, but I don't need to generate sentences based on any sort of grammar - I just need to randomly select N words from a given dictionary/vocabulary, and concatenate them into a string. I am also aware of ability to generate random strings of characters or how to use NLTK to generate "English-looking" nonsense words using n-grams, but I need the words to be actual English words from some dictionary file.

I tried doing this:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
from random import sample

n = 100
rand_words = ' '.join(sample(words, n))
```

But `words` is not an iterable so I can't use it this way. What is the correct way to create a random string of English words using NLTK's builtin dictionaries?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. Would you like to post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to use the `words()` function [corpus-structure](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html#fig-text-corpus-structure)

```
rand_words = ' '.join(sample(words.words(), n))
```